# how to change Image on Facebook Share

Tags: 2013, social, social-tag

Below is the Html I'm using in My SharePoint Page to SharePoint Page on Facebook.

```
  <!-- Facebook -->
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://SharePointSite/Pages/default.aspx" target="_blank" class="share-btn facebook">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> <span>SHARE</span>
    </a>
```

While click on Facebook Share button it will display like this.

[image]

But I want to show the Image from SharePoint Page content.

If you see the above html there is URL parameter in the anchor tag `u=http://SharePointSite/Pages/default.aspx`
 which is the SharePoint page URL.

So is there any trick to Show our custom Image.

Answer (score 1):

This post is a litle old, but you Facebook uses the open graph protocol.

In the head section of your master page, you can add attributes about your site including what image to show.

```
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://yoursite.com">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Awesome Website">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Awesome website">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://yoursite.com/images/image.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="468" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Come check out our site">
```